# Triple integral probably in spherical Coordinates: $ \iiint _{W} zy\, dz\,dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I’m trying to solve this integral:

$$ \iiint _{W} zy\, dz\,dy\,dx\,,$$

where $W$ is the volume inside $ x^{2} +y^{2} +z^{2} =1$ and $ z^{2} =x^{2} +y^{2}$.

my first attempt was to write this in spherical coordinates the following way :

$$ \int ^{2\pi }_{0} \sin\theta \ d\theta \int ^{1}_{0} \rho ^{4} \ d\rho \int ^{\frac{\pi }{2}}_{0} \sin^{2} \varphi .\cos\varphi \ d\varphi $$

but I have a feeling this is very wrong and I also get $0$ as the answer!
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer being zero is a coincidence, this doesn't change the fact that your $\varphi$ bounds are wrong. As it stands your bounds represent a hemisphere above the $xy$ plane, but what should it be really?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi would you please tell me the correct bounds? I’m very new to this and struggling a lot.

Comment: Limit for $\phi$ you should obtain from second equation.

Comment: Oh I was making a silly mistake. So if I got it right this time, the bounds would be from $ \pi /4$ to  $ 3\pi /4$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$zy$ is an odd function in both $z$ and $y$ and has even symmetry about the $xy$ and $xz$ planes (i.e. $(x,y,z)\in W \iff (x,\pm y,\pm z) \in W$) thus the integral will be zero.